# SOQL: Is it possible to order result based on Child field

Tags: soql

I want to build a query to order result based on Child field like this:

```
select id, name, other_field, (select id, name, other_field from Child__r) from Parent order by Child__r.name
```

But, I am getting an error message. I've searched Salesforce documentations, but did not find anything.

Edit: ERROR message added below:

> INVALID_FIELD:  order by Child__r.name ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:254
>
> Didn't understand relationship 'Child__r' in field path. If you are
> attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r'
> after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the
> describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Please always include any error message *verbatim*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the child object instead and pull in the parent fields using a [`Right Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Inner_Join):

```
SELECT Id, Name, SomeField__c, Parent__c, Parent__r.Name, Parent__r.OtherField__c
FROM Child__c ORDER BY Name
```

But no, you cannot sort the parent records by child values, due to the nature of a many-to-one relationship. If you have one parent with children `Alice` and `David`, and another with children `Bob` and `Charlie`, you need a way to determine which would come first. With number fields you might order by `Max`, `Min`, `Avg`, etc. But that doesn't make sense with text fields.

Comment: That is an alternative, but I want to return Parent object.

Comment: You realize it's a many-to-one relationship, right? There will be more than one name.

Comment: Yes, child-to-parent its many-to-one relationship.

Comment: One concern.. If it's a one-to-one relationship, would be possible to return Parent object?

Comment: There is no such thing.